# XML to CSV with XSLT multiple node

Tags: xml, xslt, csv

I am trying to convert xml file to CSV format using XSLT. 
My XML file has multiple root (Account) with attributes and also with children of differend types.

**Here is my XML:**

```
<SiebelMessage>
<ListOfSwiOrganizationIO>
    <Account>
        <Email>jozk8o@sk.ibm.com</Email>
        <Name>ESET</Name>
        <Address>
            <StreetAddress>Vodna 9</StreetAddress>
            <City>Nitra</City>
        </Address>
        <Contact>
            <LastName>Jozo</LastName>
            <FirstName>Sekera</FirstName>
        </Contact>
        <AccountCategory>
            <CategoryValue>90</CategoryValue>
        </AccountCategory>
        <AccountCategory>
            <CategoryValue>91</CategoryValue>
        </AccountCategory>
        <IntegrityCode>
            <IntegrityType>AllowSms</IntegrityType>
            <ConsentCode>YES</ConsentCode>
        </IntegrityCode>
        <IntegrityCode>
            <IntegrityType>AllowEmail</IntegrityType>
            <ConsentCode>YES</ConsentCode>
        </IntegrityCode>
    </Account>
    <Account>
        <Email>ferk8o@sk.ibm.com</Email>
        <Name>IBM</Name>
        <Address>
            <StreetAddress>Dlha 1</StreetAddress>
            <City>Bratislava</City>
        </Address>
        <Contact>
            <LastName>Fero</LastName>
            <FirstName>Kopacka</FirstName>
        </Contact>
        <AccountCategory>
            <CategoryValue>90</CategoryValue>
        </AccountCategory>
        <AccountCategory>
            <CategoryValue>91</CategoryValue>
        </AccountCategory>
        <IntegrityCode>
            <IntegrityType>AllowSms</IntegrityType>
            <ConsentCode>YES</ConsentCode>
        </IntegrityCode>
        <IntegrityCode>
            <IntegrityType>AllowEmail</IntegrityType>
            <ConsentCode>YES</ConsentCode>
        </IntegrityCode>
    </Account>
</ListOfSwiOrganizationIO>
```

I was able to create XSLT based on some articles here but only displaying the root attributes without children.

Required output is:

```
Email;Name;StreetAddress;City;LastName;FirstName;CategoryValue;AllowSms;AllowEmail
jozk8o@sk.ibm.com;ESET;Vodna 9;Nitra;Jozo;Sekera;90,91;YES;NOTSET
ferk8o@sk.ibm.com;IBM;Dlha 1;Bratislava;Fero;Kopacka;90,91;YES;NO
```

**Here is my current XSLT:**

```
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="';'"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<!-- Output the CSV header -->
<xsl:text>Email;Name;StreetAddress;City;LastName;FirstName;CategoryValue;AllowSms;AllowEmail&#10;</xsl:text> 
<!-- Output the values -->
<xsl:for-each select="SiebelMessage/ListOfSwiOrganizationIO/Account">
    <!-- begin values -->
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(Email, $delimiter, Name, $delimiter, ListOfAddress/Address/StreetAddress, $delimiter, ListOfAddress/Address/City, $delimiter, Contact/LastName, $delimiter, Contact/FirstName, $delimiter)"/>
    <!-- Category Values -->
    <xsl:for-each select="AccountCategory">
        <xsl:value-of select="CategoryValue"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text> 
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
    <!-- Integrity Codes -->
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(IntegrityCode[IntegrityType='AllowSms']/ConsentCode, $delimiter, IntegrityCode[IntegrityType='AllowEmail']/ConsentCode)"/>
    <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="ConsentCode=YES">
             (1)
          </xsl:when>
       </xsl:choose>
    <!-- end values -->
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text> 
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Could you please advice how to implement also children?
My current output is only:

```
EMAIL;NAME
jozk8o@sk.ibm.com;ESET;
ferk8o@sk.ibm.com;IBM;
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Is the structure of `<Account>` constant and known beforehand?

Comment: yes it is. there will be other subnodes(cihldren of the Account) I have mentioned just few to make it simplier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the structure is constant and known beforehand, I'd suggest you construct your output by naming the input elements **explicitly**:

**XSLT 1.0**
***(edited to match the updated question)***

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="';'"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- Output the CSV header -->
    <xsl:text>Email;Name;StreetAddress;City;LastName;FirstName;CategoryValue;AllowSms;AllowEmail&#10;</xsl:text> 
    <!-- Output the values -->
    <xsl:for-each select="SiebelMessage/ListOfSwiOrganizationIO/Account">
        <!-- begin values -->
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(Email, $delimiter, Name, $delimiter, Address/StreetAddress, $delimiter, Address/City, $delimiter, Contact/LastName, $delimiter, Contact/FirstName, $delimiter)"/>
        <!-- Category Values -->
        <xsl:for-each select="AccountCategory">
            <xsl:value-of select="CategoryValue"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text> 
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
        <!-- Integrity Codes -->
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(IntegrityCode[IntegrityType='AllowSms']/ConsentCode, $delimiter, IntegrityCode[IntegrityType='AllowEmail']/ConsentCode)"/>
        <!-- end values -->
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text> 
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This has the advantage of both speed and no unnecessary "moving parts".

Comment: Thank you, this helped. But there are another 2 things. I have updated XML and required CSV Output. 
1) There can be more then one "AccountCategory" which need to be inseted in one column(in excel) separated by comma (e.g. 90,91)
2) There can be more then one "IntegrityCode". But there will be fixed columns in header with the names of the attribute "IntegrityType"(AllowSms;AllowEmail). Please see output CSV.
Could you please advice how to implement this last 2 things? Thank you very much

Comment: @user3804719 See the edit to my post.-- Note: I don't see the value of "NOTSET" in your input.

Comment: Respect Michael, you are great! I just forget to update values in XML. but there can be 3 values: YES, NO, NOTSET. would be also possible to replace in output 1,0,""? I mean replace YES->1, NO->0, NOTSET-> "" (empty string).

Comment: @user3804719 Come now, this is trivial: just use `<xsl:choose>`.

Comment: hm, Im really beginner in XSL, could you pls show the example? I check the function how to use, but I have little bit problem how to implement...

Comment: @user3804719 Example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256169%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I added choose function but its ignoring. Maybe I inserted it on wrong place. I updated my first post and XSLT part

Comment: I tried also to put it onto the select, but then I got an error that its unexpected child. Please, could you adapt this change to my XSLT? I would really appreciate it.